# profile page in php with different results

Tags: php

The following piece of code displays my name if I see my profile page. I want to modify it, so that if I will visit the profile page of another user, his profile page to displays both name and email.

```
<?php

if(  isset($_GET['email']) === true  &&  empty($_GET['email']) === false  ){

  $email    = $_GET['email'];

  if(user_exists($email) === true) {

    $user_id = user_id_from_email($email); 

    $profile_data   = user_data($user_id,'name','email');

    echo $profile_data['name'];
?>
```

Comment: Did you create a session when you are logged in with the user id or any informations to see if it's you or not ?

Comment: any idea how to do this?

Comment: You need to create session to store that kind of data. When an user is connecting to your website by auth, you have to create a session for this user. The basic way is to do $_SESSION['user_id'] = user_id for your user. You can also store username and other stuff but be careful and never put some secret data as password or credit card number.

Comment: What's the output of variable $profile_data ?

Comment: displays the name and email from user...what I want tested and works with the answer I just posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(  $session_user_id !== $user_id ){echo $profile_data['email'];}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only piece that is missing is to display email:

```
echo $profile_data['name'] . "\n";
echo $profile_data['email'];
```

Comment: that would display name and email in all profile pages. I want logged in user that visits his profile page to view only his name. If he will visit other profile pages, then to view name and email